# PostgreSQL: Column Disk usage

Tags: database, postgresql, disk

I have a big table on my database, but it has a lot of empty fields on every column, and I´d like to know how much does every column use.

Is there any way to know how much disk space is each tables columns using?

Comment: `pg_column_size()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using [`pg_column_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-admin.html), it will return the column size in bytes:

```
SELECT sum(pg_column_size(column)) FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 3):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/storage-page-layout.html#STORAGE-TUPLE-LAYOUT) mentions, NULL values are indicated in the *null bitmap* of every tuple, which is always present if the table has nullable columns.

So a NULL value consumes no extra space on disk.

If you design tables with very many columns, rethink your design.