# Postgres Accurate Column Disk Usage Percentage of Table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am trying to figure out an accurate representation of what percentage of a table's disk usage a certain column makes up. If you use a combinations of solutions from [PostgreSQL: Column Disk usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375545/postgresql-column-disk-usage) and [How do you find the disk size of a Postgres / PostgreSQL table and its indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596624/how-do-you-find-the-disk-size-of-a-postgres-postgresql-table-and-its-indexes), you'll get a solution such as:

```sql
select sum(pg_column_size('column_1'))      as column_1,
       sum(pg_column_size('column_2'))      as column_2,
       pg_total_relation_size('table_name') as total_size
from table_name;
```

However, there are some peculiarities with the output I can't reconcile:

1. The output of `pg_total_relation_size` is *way* larger than the sum of all of the individual columns (i.e. `sum(pg_column_size('column_1')) + sum(pg_column_size('column_2'))` ... Even if I subtract the size of indexes on the table and size of TOAST, the values are very different. For example, the sum of all of my column sizes is equal to `1217720` bytes, but according to PG the size of the table (excluding indexes and toast) is `6963200`. Where can that large of a discrepancy be coming from?
2. If I run the query above against two entirely different servers, and then compute my percentages as `sum(pg_column_size('column_1')) / (sum(pg_column_size('column_1')) + sum(pg_column_size('column_2'))` the percentages are identical, despite wildly different data sets of strings, jsonb, etc.

I feel like I am missing something obvious but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like using `sum(octet_length(column_1::text))` for text/varchar/json/jsonb/tsvector columns gives me a more accurate representation of what I'm looking for

Comment: pg_column_size('column_1') gives you the size of the string 'column_1' (including the size marker)

Comment: @jjanes I can't believe I missed that, thank you!